# Is my HDD the reason my PC got slow?

Tags: hard-drive

My pc really got slow some months ago just like that. And I am trying to narrow the reason down.

I have downloaded CrystalDisk to try and have information about the disk. But I don't even know what info it is giving me. So I come here to ask you if you know if any info of the following could tell if the disk is the reason for the slowness or not.

[image]

I have also reinstalled windows on the disk and the problems continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the power setting being set at Power Saver not High Performace.

My face when the games regained their usual performance levels had to be priceless.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have some money to spare, an SSD is faster in many ways.  You've demonstrated that you're OK with reinstalling the OS and everything else, so the project to install an SSD for primary storage should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The "Current" and "Worst" values seem to be far enough away from "Threshold" and as "Health Status" says, the disk seems to be in a good condition. S.M.A.R.T is pretty good in detecting whether a disk will fail in the next time or not.

I personally would do a short speedtest on that drive to check its read/write speed and access time.

Comment: Why would the speed of a drive suddenly change? More likely, it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before you blame hardware for an unexplained change in PC speed, look at the software that uses up resources. For Windows:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open Task Manager.
- Click on the *Details* tab.
- Click on the header for *CPU* to see what process use the most CPU time.
- Do the same for *Memory*.
- Add *I/O read bytes* and *I/O write bytes*, if not showing, and click on them in turn.

[image: Task Manager - Details]

You may have some run-away process hogging CPU time, something consuming memory, etc.

**You may also have malware slowing your PC,** e.g., coin miner, so perform a virus scan.

Finally, you may have filled your HDD. How much free space is available?

Comment: Hi @DrMishePippik, I have reinstalled windows in the HDD. So I disregard software problems. Also, the disk is pretty much empty. I will have a look at the task manager. Although I have no clue how to read information from I/O read/write bytes.